# Got a JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to follow a online tutorial to create this login, but I receive this error. I tried this on localhost but it doesn't work on a server. Can anybody tell me what is my mistake please. Here's my code:

```js
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

[image: logcat]

Comment: Temporarily comment all the lines inside onResponse, only leave `Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response);` then post your new logcat info

Comment: instead of adding image,add log in question itself.

Comment: after i comment all the lines, it just keeps logging in. Logcat: D/RegisterActivity: Login Response:

Comment: your response is null,
*not receiving any string*

Comment: can you tell me how should i correct this please? I have tried it on localhost and it worked.

Comment: I also got the JSONException once working on volley, and by seeing your code, I guess it is due to same reason. So, I will help you out but first tell me ,Is "user" the only json object you have in the string "response" or better, tell me, the format of your string "response" .

Comment: @user3247709 did you tried running your POST request in Postman chrome extension?

Comment: Yes user is the only table i have in my database

Comment: You did not send any body data (username, password) with this POST request.

Answer (score 0):

It means either the response is not in JSON format or the client side did not get any response at all. Try to following steps.:-
 1.Before using the URL in the application check it in a web browser if you are getting the desired response or not. If there is any server side error it will be displayed in the web browser.
2. Now check the serve side response with a JSON validator to check if the response is a valid JSON or not
3.If your server side is then use logcat or toast message to print your response and check the response.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the way to solve it. It's the codes in the DB_Functions.php file that caused the problem. I have changed the code a bit then it works now. Thanks so much you guys for the help.I have also attached the code in case someone ran into the same problem. Good luck guys

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
   $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

// check for result

   $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
      $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $salt = $result['salt'];
      $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
      $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
```